# scikit, catagorical columns, decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I did find threads about scikit catagorical variables. But I could not find a easy answer. I do realise while building decision tree, sklearn errors out for catagorical data and there are suggestions for Vectorizer etc. I tried evrything yet I am not able to create a decision tree. My table has a lot of columns with strings and I tried vectorizer,multilabelbinerizer etc. Nothings seenms to work. I am not able to export_graphviz and display the tree, as there is no tree at all. I am pretty new to this. 
I sincerely request to help me understand how to handle these columns. I am splitting the data 80-20 for training and test. Then I am trying to build a tree. Just a quick piece of code:

```
  dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
  mlb = preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()
  n_train = mlb.fit_transform(train)
  n_test = mlb.transform(test) 
  dec_tree=dtree.fit(n_train,n_test)
```

I do get this as answer and I am confused:

```
  DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini',  
        max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        random_state=0, splitter='best')
```

Please advise on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your categorical variables usable by the classifier, one possibility is to use [OneHodEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) from scikit-learn.

You should watch out that no variable has levels with too few occurrences. If you don't want to or cannot check this manually, use a threshold on the variance of variables with [VarianceThreshold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.html).

---

**Other possibility if you were using pandas** DataFrame as structure, `pandas.get_dummies(DataFrame["variable"])` will build the dummy variables for you.

Comment: Thank you @MathieuB  , as a quickfix I assigned integer values to string classes. I will try your suggestion and let you know soon if I have further doubts. Thanks again!

Comment: @Arvin you're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer and upvote if useful ;)

Comment: @ Mathieu B I am very sorry I dont have enough reputation points to upvote as of now :D.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to encode your features.you should use your label(column that you want to predict) as second parameter in dtree.fit() function but you use your test data as second parameter.
check [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit) to know correct way to use DecisionTreeClassifier fit function